# What are the proper steps to avoid conflicts and to merge with master?

Tags: git

there 2 branches: master and mretana

I need to know what are the steps I need to follow up in order to push some changes.

**1st case:**

I need to merge from master to my branch mretana because master is up to date.

These are the steps I am following

```
1 commit my changes
2 push my changes
3 switch to branch master
4 pull origin master
3 switch to branch mretana
4 git merge master
```

with those steps, if some was working in a file named `file.js` and me too, then a conflict comes up because me and my co-worker were working in the same file. **Is that behavior the proper one ?**

**2nd case:**

if I don't to merge master but only upload my changes:

```
1 commit my changes
2 push my changes
```

so:

1 - is there any other way to merge master ?

2 - is there a way to avoid conflicts ?

Comment: It is proper to manually merge conflicts.  Don't try to push changes without merging, it won't work (and if you try to make it work by using `-f`, you'll only destroy your co-worker's data).

Comment: "then a conflict comes up because me and my co-worker were working in the same file" --- it only comes when you edited exactly the same lines and it couldn't have been resolved automatically. So, **NO**, the behaviour you explained is not the proper and is not expected.

Comment: @DietrichEpp "Don't try to push changes without merging, it won't work" --- that's not correct, at least in the context of the "2nd case" example. OP has made changes in their branch and pushed their branch.

Comment: @zerkms so it is normal to get a conflict if we both are working in the same lines ?\

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer it is normal - git cannot tell what exactly to do in such case. Well, even human beings not always can tell what to do in such case.

Comment: @DietrichEpp so I need to first only commit my changes and then go to master, pull changes on master, then go to my branch, merge master and then push my changes ?

Comment: sorry guys, but I could not get you, remember I have 2 different cases here. That's why I am a little confuse.

Comment: It's not clear what is not obvious for you.

Comment: @zerkms do not take it personal, I mean, is because both are giving me different suggestions, I appreciate it that, but the 1st guy says something and then you say " that's not correct". Sorry, but thank you for help

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer so? What would I say if their advice was not correct? "Don't try to push changes without merging, it won't work" --- this is imprecise, since you definitely can push without merging.

Comment: @zerkms can you post an answer with the steps I need to follow up in both cases?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer "I need to follow up in both cases?" --- I answered the exact questions you asked. It's not clear again what exactly is confusing you in git and what you're asking - so I tried to play pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git may seem like magic but it isn't. It does a lot of things much better than old style version control systems (I'm looking at you SVN) but at some points it has to rely on human intervention to understand intentionality.  Conflicts are just git saying to you "I don't know what you intended to do here, please help me"

1) The process you going through is not problematic. However, I will point out pushing your changes before you merge in master to it is unnecessary.  The conflict occurs because as others have stated you and your coworker have changed something that git cannot resolve and it needs you to help it understand. There are tools that will help you with this or you can just edit the conflicted files as are appropriate.

2) The way to avoid conflicts is to not touch the same code as your coworker when you are doing work. Even in well factored code bases it is not always possible, so just learn how to deal with conflict resolution.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions directly:

> Is that behavior the proper one ?

It's not as you described it. Conflicts appear when it cannot be merged automatically (if it was chosen to do so, it's by default). It usually happens when the same line was edited in different changesets hence cannot be merged automatically.

> 1 - is there any other way to merge master ?

You merge with `git merge`.

> 2 - is there a way to avoid conflicts ?

Don't edit the same lines of code.

Comment: and if I am going to update my branch with master, before do ```checkout master```, do I need to push my changes or only commit them ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer your personal branch lives separately from `master`. It's an isolated thing. So if you want to push your branch - do that, `master` has no influence on it.